# Allow registered users to edit Talk pages only

Tags: mediawiki

I've been using mediawiki for a while now and had it set up so that only I can edit pages:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['edit'] = true;
```

However, I'd like registered users to be able to create/edit talk pages. How would I go about doing this? Other than the above, I don't have any experience with mediawiki permissions, but from looking at [this page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aUser_rights), it seems that you must have the edit permission to alter talk pages, leaving me to then restrict creating new pages and protecting every page. Is there a better way?

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why this question is off topic? I've read the FAQ, and I still don't understand. It's a question related to software development with a specific, achievable goal.

Comment: I guess they think it should go on ServerFault or something. I put it here as this is where similar MediaWiki questions were, and it could have required modifying the code.

Comment: Yeah. I've looked at ServerFault and there aren't many people answering MediaWiki related questions on it. Regardless, if they think it should have gone there, they should have migrated it instead of closing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it out of the box since MediaWiki treats editing a Talk page the same as editing any other page in the wiki but check out the [Talkright](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aTalkright) extension. It does what you want.